# Indexed whole life insurance

Tags: whole-life

Is it wise to buy indexed whole life insurance?   I am evaluating an option that limits upside at 10% per year  with no down side.  I am Currently 55 and in good health with about 10 years left to work.

Comment: This duplicate might not be exactly what you're looking for, but search the site for "Whole Life" and you will find many similar questions. In short - commissions on these products are quite profitable for agents, so they get pushed very aggressively, but very rarely make sense. Buy term life insurance for protection of your family's livelihoods if necessary, and use the excess available to buy a separate investment without the crazy high fees. Don't mix the two products together.

Comment: Related: [Buying Whole Life Insurance with adjustable term protection at 27?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/56667/10997)

Comment: No, Whole life is a terrible product.  Buy level term.

Comment: Do you have any people that depend on your income? If not, you probably don't need any life insurance at all. (I ask because *most* 55 year olds do not have any dependents and at least some retirement savings).